# I can't get the soft body to follow the empties

Tags: objects

I am basically working on a tetherball.

I have tried a lot of different methods and nothing really works.

Basically, I have a girl and she has the ball in her hands. I have already animated the ball. I am trying to animate the rope and make it collide around the pole.

I have tried using a cube, etc, but no matter the setting, hooks, armatures, etc...

I cannot get the bottom of the end of the rope to follow the empty. It just wiggles in place.

I tried opening a new file, and it did the same thing. The bottom of the rectangle won't move. It turns, slightly, no matter the vertex group/setting, etc.

I was thinking I could try anti gravity?

Regardless....why won't it follow the bottom? I don't comprehend.

[image]

EDIT:

https://youtu.be/_A43B_jAxd8

For a working example of what I mean.

I am trying to get said bottom to move...pick up...go against gravity...something of that nature.

I have tried so many settings I must be losing my mind. :P Not that I had much to begin with. XD

[image]

Answer (score 4):

since you didn't show us any really useful information of your setup (like order of your modifier, goal, soft body settings) i explain how a general setup works:

from a default cube, select 4 vertices and extrude a few times:

[image]

select one vertex, CTRL-H -> to new object

[image]

then select that one vertex and create a vertex group for that (don't forget to press "assign".

[image]

now add softbody and choose your vertex group for goal:

[image]

now hit spacebar to "run animation", in object mode select your empty and move it around.

[image]

if you don't want it too crazy, just increase damping, and shade smooth does make your object look better, maybe even add a subdivision surface modifier after soft body[image]

the order of the modifiers is crucial here.

First the hook, then soft body, then subdivision.

Changing the order will break the simulation and/or change the behaviour!

Comment: Sorry about that! Thanks for the throughout comment. Sorry for the confusion! Yes, I have done all this. Let me post some screenshots of my actual project to give some clarification.

Comment: Better would be providing your blend file so we can check it out

Comment: Added a YT vid and the blend file of the sample. And don't take any of my settings too seriously for the soft body. I've tried all kinds of vertex groups, all kinds of settings, I even made my own document so I can remember what each setting means because it's been way too long since I used soft bodies lol. The fact I can't pick up the other end is a mystery I just...cannot solve, apparently, haha! Thank you for your response.